# How to create Transition Matrix (Markov) in R?

Tags: r

I've read the similar questions out there but I was not able to get the code right, so if anyone can help it would be very good.

I have a financial dataset similar to this:

```
Year  ID  Return  Quintile
1      A   -0,3      1
2      A   -0,2      2
3      B    1,5      5
3      C    0,1      3
4      C    0,1      3
```

For each year, I have information regarding many investors' IDs. For some ID's I have 20 years of data, for others, I only have 2 or 3 years of data. I was able to rank the data in performance quintiles (based on returns) from 1 to 5. I need to do a probability transition matrix.
Basically, I need to know the probability that an ID that was in quintile 1 remains on quintile 1 in the next year, or moves into quintile 2, 3, 4 or 5. I also need to do the same for a 2 years horizon.
.

Should be something like this (ifirst and second tables, and instead of A, B, C should have 1, 2 , 3 etc)
[image: Text]

Ps. Do I need to balance the data frame? I.e. only analyze ID's that have, let's say, 10 years of consecutive data? Otherwise, an ID that only has two years of returns, and changes its quintile, has a 100% probability of changing state and may disturb the end result.
Thanks a lot, and sorry for the long post.

Comment: look at package msm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dat1 <- read.table(text="
Year  ID  Return  Quintile
1      A   -0,3      1
2      A   -0,2      2
3      B    1,5      5
3      C    0,1      3
4      C    0,1      3
", header=TRUE)
```

You can use `statetable.msm` from the `msm` package to count the transitions in your dataset, stratified by ID:

```
msm::statetable.msm(Quintile, ID, data=dat1)

    to
from 1 2 3 5
   1 0 1 0 0
   3 0 0 1 0
```

This will give you counts, but you could use `prop.table` to give you row percentages.  This will rely on you having consecutive years for each subject though.

With this tiny amount of data it's not possible, but to estimate the tranistion matrix properly you could use `msm` function as follows:

```
# set allowed transitions
qm <- matrix(1,nrow=5, ncol=5)
# estimate the matrix
q1 <- msm::msm(Quintile ~ Year , subject = ID, data=dat1, qmatrix = qm)
```

You could then take this matrix and calculate the transition matrix for any given time period.  But this doesn't work with only two transitions observed.  Look at the documentation for `msm` to understand how it works.

Comment: I might remove the data that does not have consecutive years... so then I can just run the second part of the code you provided? (btw, the statetable part of the code is working, thanks)

Comment: sorry maybe I wasn't clear... using the `msm` function to estimate the transition matrix you can have data with missing states.  the `statetable` function will only count observed transitions though, it ignores the `year` variable so if you use this to approximate your 1-year matrix this you are making the assumption that every observed transition is between adjacent years.

Comment: markov chains are difficult, i strongly advise you read the `msm` documentation.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your answers.  I removed the non-consecutive data (it's just easier that way) and now I am able to use state.table and prop.table to generate the transition matrix. But, as I understand, this way i am not using msm, and I will not be able to generate these matrixes for other time periods?

Comment: If `P` is the 1-year transition matrix then `P%*%P` is the two year matrix etc (if the Markov assumption holds).

Comment: btw, the second part of your code, which i believe is the msm, is not running... i get the following error -  Error in Ccall.msm(params, do.what = "lik", ...) : 
  numerical overflow in calculating likelihood

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239674/discussion-between-portocrl-and-george-savva).